# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I receive this error when trying to login using `ipadd/loginpage.aspx`. This happens when I try to login on my Local Area Network using a different machine:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\StoreDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Does the file exist on the host?  Does the IIS user have access to it?

Comment: What fixes have you tried?

Comment: i have restarted the iis ,and i have changed the connection string of the database

Comment: This will tell you if the database exists:

SELECT DB_ID('Electric')

If you see a number, it does.  If you receive a NULL, it does not.  From there, look at accessibility in IIS.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a database nor attached a database because you have no privileged to do so. Here's my workaround:

First, run the SQL Server Management Studio as "administrator". Then, login to your account. Next, click the Security folder --> click Logins --> choose your account name --> check the properties and verify the status if you have permission to connect to database engine.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I tried these steps already and it just says 'User does not have permission to perform this action'.  I'm an admin on my machine.  How can I elevate my privileges on my own local databases?